# Javascript multiplication of two numbers returns NaN

Tags: javascript, function, object, nan

I am a more of C++ and Java programmer and this is the first time I am trying to do something with javascript. I have an Object that holds an array, and a function that is supposed to return the length of that array.

```
    var graphData = {
       labels : ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
       numData : function() {
          return (Number(this.labels.length));}
       }
```

Now what I am trying to do is to adjust the size of a div based on the size of this array .

I have

```
    var barWidth = 13;
    var viewWidth = barWidth * graphData.numData;
```

Now this just isn't working. When I checked the typeof viewWidth it returned NaN. I also tried "casting" the operands to Number() but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure graphData is defined exactly as you put it here? Because that return and the semicolon at the end of the same line would be two syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks I made the edit .

Comment: So you do have a function there. You have to **call** the function as well.

Comment: `this.labels.length` is already a `Number`. Why are you casting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function as `graphData.numData()` and not `graphData.numData` since it's not a property and that will fix the problem.

```
var graphData = {
   labels : ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
   numData : function(){return +(this.labels.length);}
}

var barWidth = 13;
var viewWidth = barWidth * graphData.numData();
```

Comment: Please **explain** the problem and your solution.

Comment: @vjdhama I actually have it enclosed in in a function expression.

Comment: Another factor in the solution is that, in `graphData.numData` is a function, not a number. So, `barWidth * graphData.numData` will generate a `NaN`, but `barWidth * graphData.numData()` will retrieve the desired value and then multiply it by `barWidth`.